# How to add custom js file to angular component like css file

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular.
Can anyone say how can I add custom js file in angular template.

`@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})`

**UPDATED**

i want to add the below code

```
$("#single-slider").owlCarousel({
      navigation: true,
      slideSpeed: 600,
      autoPlay: 6000,
      singleItem: true,
      pagination: false,
      navigationText: [
          "<i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i>",
          "<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i>"
      ],
  });
```

Comment: add in your `home.component.html`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But it is not working in that way.
Can you show me with example.

Comment: `<script src="yoururl">` and declare your varibale what you use.

Comment: sorry its not working. script tag is removed in output.

Comment: @RachChen, script tags are automatically removed by Angular DOM Sanitizer. You'll either have to disable the DOM sanitizer to make your solution work or if you are not ready to do that, please check my answer below.

Comment: take a try. I add in index.html in root folder and it's not be Sanitizered

Comment: @RachChen, this way you are linking the js to the whole application and this js will be loaded every time which is not recommended.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal hi,it's `spa` and it would only one time loaded even route to any page.

Comment: @RachChen, it will load the file again if the page is refereshed

Comment: @AkashAgrawal If the page is refereshed, it would loaded **whole** project again. The point isn't loaded duplicated and it wouldn't happened because of `SPA`.Apparently, use your way is cool and work but every sinle page is refreshed then loaded the same javascript file inside your website.

Comment: Your perspective is based on `lazy loading` , it gonna loaded after routing your own page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `<script>` in your HTML but **IT WON'T WORK** because while building the app the Angular DOMSantizer removes all the `<script>`.

So you have to load the custom js the way @trichetriche showed. But, if the js is required only for one component then there's a workaround which is kind of hacky.

You can load the js just after the DOM has been loaded/initialized in the `ngAfterViewInit()`. This way Angular DOMSantizer doesn't know about the `<script>`.

Here you go:

```
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {};

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "../path-to-your-js-or-external-URL";
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
}
```

For more info, refer this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. The problem is that many blogs, articles and tutorials are in plain JS but the industry uses TS because of the frameworks. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

**But**, you can add it in your application as a global script by addiing it in `angular-cli.json`file :

```
"scripts": [
  "assets/xxx.js", // path to assets file
  "../node_modules/moment/moment.js" // Path to node modules dependency
],
```

Comment: Hey thanks. i already tried that one. But it is not triggering. Just updated my question please check.

Comment: What do you mean it's not triggering ? The code has errors, it does nothing, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

3 main steps to include js in angular

- Add your script.js in assets/scripts and angular-cli package
- In your js file in assets/scripts you must have window.initMethod = function() { ... your code ... }
- In your component.ts declare let initMethod: any;