# How to add a custom JS file to Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to learn Angular and as part of learning, I need to add some JS logic to one of my components which is already in a separate JS file. There is an answer to a very similar question ([How to add custom js file to angular component like css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47829032/how-to-add-custom-js-file-to-angular-component-like-css-file)). I did as it recommends, but it looks like something is missing. Please help me understand, what did I do wrong?

I created the file `custom.js` and saved it in the `src/assets` folder (just trying to see what declaration will work, as I see few different styles):

```
(function customTestHello1() {
    console.log("customTestHello1: Hello!!!"); 
    alert('customTestHello1: Hello!!!');
})()

function customTestHello2() {
    console.log("customTestHell2: Hello!!!"); 
    alert('customTestHell2: Hello!!!');
}
```

I included this file in `angular.json`:

> "scripts": [
> "src/assets/custom.js"
> ]

In the `ts-file` of my component, I added

```
declare const customTestHello1: any;
declare const customTestHello2: any;
```

and in the `ngOnInit` function of the component added call of these functions

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    customTestHello1();
    //customTestHello2();
  }
```

When I opened my page I saw an error in the console:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: customTestHello1 is not defined
    at MyComponent.ngOnInit (my.component.ts:20)
    at callHook (core.js:3038)
    at callHooks (core.js:3008)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2960)
    at refreshView (core.js:7186)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8279)
    at refreshView (core.js:7195)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8325)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6964)
    at refreshView (core.js:7221)
```

The result is the same even if I uncomment "customTestHello2()".

What do I do wrong? How can I embed JS into an Angular project into a component?

If I put following to my script:

`window.initMethod = function() { console.log("customInitMethod: Hello!"); }`

this to myComponent.ts:

`let initMethod: any;`

and call it:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    initMethod();
    //customTestHello1();
    //customTestHello2();
  }
```

I get another error:

> core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: initMethod is not a function
> at MyComponent.ngOnInit (pingball.component.ts:21)
> at callHook (core.js:3038)
> at callHooks (core.js:3008)
> at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2960)
> at refreshView (core.js:7186)
> at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8279)
> at refreshView (core.js:7195)
> at refreshComponent (core.js:8325)
> at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6964)
> at refreshView (core.js:7221)

Please advise!

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. I would also benefit a lot if you give a good tutorial that does not have an obsolete samples.

Answer (score 1):

import the custom.js file in the component in which you are going to use.

Comment: Thanks! This helped to call 'customTestHello1'. Apparently, when the function is defined the way it is, it will be automatically called. Though, I can't understand when exactly it is called? It looks like this happens before the browser to loads DOM.
How can I call a specific function from inside of 'ngOnInit'ngOnInit?

Answer (score 0):

Create an angular service to call your `customTestHello1()` method in your component after importing that service in the respective component. Make sure to add service in providers array of module.ts.
For service creation details you can refer
: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4